# Searching matching rows in different columns

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am looking for a function that can find matches in between the columns and output if it finds a matching row outputs `"has matches"` else `"no matches"`

for example

```
df = data.frame(id=c("good","bad","ugly","dirty","clean","frenzy"),di=c(1,2,"good","dirty",4,"ugly"))

> df
      id    di
1   good     1
2    bad     2
3   ugly  good
4  dirty dirty
5  clean     4
6 frenzy  ugly
```

I want to check `di` column has matches or not in `id` column such that

```
 > df
          id    di  match
    1   good     1  no matches
    2    bad     2  no matches
    3   ugly  good  has matches
    4  dirty dirty  has matches
    5  clean     4  no matches
    6 frenzy  ugly  has matches
```

This kind of approach what I am looking for

```
match_func <- function(x,y){

  }

df%>%
  do(match_func(.$id,.$di))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `%in%` with `ifelse`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(match = ifelse(di %in% id, "has matches", "no matches"))
```

Or `case_when`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(match = case_when(di %in% id ~ "has matches",
                                   TRUE ~ "no matches"))
```

---

This can be directly wrapped in a function. Assuming that we are passing unquoted names, then convert it to quosure with `enquo` and then evaluate within the `mutate` by `!!`

```
f1  <- function(dat, col1, col2) {
    col1 = enquo(col1)
    col2 = enquo(col2)
    dat %>%
        mutate(match = case_when(!! (col1) %in% !!(col2) ~ "has matches", 
                 TRUE ~ "no matches"))
}
f1(df, di, id)
#      id    di       match
#1   good     1  no matches
#2    bad     2  no matches
#3   ugly  good has matches
#4  dirty dirty has matches
#5  clean     4  no matches
#6 frenzy  ugly has matches
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Great to have directly inside of `dplyr` pipeline. If someone wants build a function to do it ?

Comment: when I ran the `f1` function I got  `Error in !(col2) : invalid argument type`

Comment: @Alexander  I am using dplyr 0.7.4  What is your package version?

Comment: dplyr 0.7.4 and R 3.4.3.

Comment: That is strange as it is working for me.  Have you loaded any other package such as plyr which masks mutate

Comment: I haven't loaded plyr package. Maybe R version is different ? Ok if it is working in your pc that's fair enough. I'll upgrade the R version:))

Comment: I have R3.4.3 as well

Comment: @Alexander Can you try on a fresh session.  How about u change `enquo` to `rlang::enquo` (though it is not needed on my side)

Comment: Just tried with fresh session and only loaded dplyr but still the same error!

Comment: @Alexander Can you also check version of `rlang`  I tried with `rlang_0.1.6.9003`  Try changing the `!!` to `UQ(col1)` and `UQ(col2)`

Comment: mine is 0.1.4. I installed updated rlang and now its working! thank you for your guidance always!

Answer (score 4):

Using `base R` and without `if/else` statement, you can compute `match` column with:

```
df$match <- c("no matches", "has matches")[(df$di %in% df$id) + 1]
df
#      id    di       match
#1   good     1  no matches
#2    bad     2  no matches
#3   ugly  good has matches
#4  dirty dirty has matches
#5  clean     4  no matches
#6 frenzy  ugly has matches
```